# Detecting if an argument to a macro is just a string

Tags: macros, catcodes

Let's say I construct a macro like \keywords{this, that, other} that accepts an argument, but I want to reject any argument that contains macros or anything besides space, newline, and characters (meaning I raise a \ClassError). Presumably this means I would reject anything that contained catcodes other than 5,10,11,12. It seems like it should be possible to implement this, but I have not the slightest idea how.

Comment: Use `\tl_analysis_map_inline` and build up from there. (it's a bit clumsy but should be straightforward how to.) Alternative includes \str_if_in \c_backslash_str.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The concept of “string” is quite vague. Besides, you probably don't want to reject something such as “étale cohomology”, which would be a perfectly fine keyword in a mathematical paper.

You probably want to ensure that the author types in `étale` rather than `\'etale`, in order to ease extraction for other usages.

`expl3` has the feature you want, namely, `\text_purify:n`. This removes commands but is friendly to UTF-8 characters also in `pdflatex`. You can then compare the result of applying `\text_purify:n` to the argument with the argument itself.

```
\documentclass{article}

% this would go in the class file
\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\keywords}{m}
 {
  \mccurleyclass_keywords:n { #1 }
 }

\prg_generate_conditional_variant:Nnn \tl_if_eq:nn { e } { T,F,TF }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \mccurleyclass_keywords:n
 {
  % check whether the argument only contains standard text
  \tl_if_eq:enTF { \text_purify:n { #1 } } { #1 }
   {% good!
    \__mccurleyclass_keywords_print:n { #1 }
   }
   {%
    \msg_error:nn { mccurleyclass } { invalid-keywords }
   }
 }

\prop_gput:Nnn \g_msg_module_type_prop { mccurleyclass } { Class }

\msg_new:nnnn { mccurleyclass } { invalid-keywords }
 {
  Illegal~keywords
 }
 {
  Please~use~only~standard~text~in~keywords
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \__mccurleyclass_keywords_print:n
 {
  \par\addvspace{\topsep}
  \noindent\textbf{Keywords}\quad #1
  \par\addvspace{\topsep}
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\keywords{this, that, other} % good

\keywords{étale cohomology, something else} % good

\keywords{\'etale cohomology, something else} % bad

\keywords{\textit{étale} cohomology, something else} % bad

\end{document}
```

The first two pass the test, the last two don't and issue the message

```
! Class mccurleyclass Error: Illegal keywords

For immediate help type H <return>.
 ...

l.52 ...textit{étale} cohomology, something else}
                                                   % bad
? h

Please use only standard text in keywords
```

Comment: The concept of "string" is only vague in LaTeX. Everywhere else it means UTF-8 string.

Comment: That's an excellent answer. I tested it with quite a few inputs and it seems to do exactly what I want.